# JAAS Policy in Eclipse RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp, jaas

My "deny all" policy does **not** cause `SecurityException` in Eclipse RCP part. But works properly in plain java class test — `checkPermission` throws `SecurityException`.

I'm using custom policy with `implies` method. It denies all subjects that have any principal. Check is done inside `doAs` in some RCP ViewPart.

**ViewPart.** *Settings my policy, creating subject with principal, running doAs for that subject and checking permission:*

```
public class MyPart extends ViewPart {
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        Policy.setPolicy(new MyPolicy());
        Subject subject = new Subject();
        subject.getPrincipals().add(new Principal() {
            public String getName() {
                return "MyPrincipal";
            }
        });
        Subject.doAs(subject, new PrivilegedAction<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object run() {
                try {
                    AccessController.checkPermission(new MyPerm("abc"));
                }
                catch(SecurityException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Policy.** *Policy that denies all actions for subjects with principal:*

```
public class MyPolicy extends java.security.Policy {
    public boolean implies(ProtectionDomain domain, Permission permission) {
        if (domain.getPrincipals().length == 0) {
            //not inside of doAs
            return true;
        }

        System.out.println("deny all");
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Simple permission for test:**

```
public class MyPerm extends Permission {
    public MyPerm(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public boolean implies(Permission permission) {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return false;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return 0;
    }

    public String getActions() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Both in plain java class test and in Eclipse RCP, I can see *"deny all"* string in console. So, my policy is applied in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not succeeded to make JAAS Policy work properly in RCP. Finished with dirty hack workaround: throwing `AccessControlException` right from the place, where Policy returns false.

**Example:**

```
public class MyPolicy extends java.security.Policy {
    public boolean implies(ProtectionDomain domain, Permission permission) {
        ...
        System.out.println("deny all");
        throw new AccessControlException("Access denied");
        return false;
    }
}
```